# pedido de apoio em otimização, correção de comando de shell para mac

Tags: bash, shell, osx, unix

Procuro saber qual a melhor forma de otimizar o seguinte comando de *shell* no *Mac OSX*, de modo a cumprir a função que se pretende que é basicamente copiar todos os ficheiros **xx** para a pasta **xx2**:

```
ditto $(mdfind xx1) ~/Desktop/xx2
```

ou então

```
ditto $(mdfind -onlyin ~/xx1) ~/Desktop/xx2
```

Answer (score 0):

use o `rsync`

```
rsync -av xx1/ xx2/
```